# accessing value of XML file in javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, xml-parsing, xmlhttprequest

I load an XML document using XMLHTTPRequest in my js file as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RMFSFile xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<Host>www.example.com</Host>
<Port>8888</Port>   
<Uri>www.example.com</Uri>
<Path>
    <HD>
        <UNC>path1</UNC>
    </HD>
    <SD>
        <UNC>path2</UNC>
    </SD>
</Path>
```

I am trying to SELECT the value of "**UNC**" for HD using javascript.

I have tried something like below, which didn't work:

```
      var x = xml.getElementsByTagName('Path')[0];
      var y = x.getElementsByTagName('HD');
      var z = y.getElementsByTagName('UNC');
```

Any idea How Can I retrieve the Path?

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` returns a `collection` - as you seem to realise with `var x` and forget in the very next line of code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `getElementsByTagName` correctly in the first line, then incorrectly after that

It should be

```
  var x = xml.getElementsByTagName('Path')[0];
  var y = x.getElementsByTagName('HD')[0];
  var z = y.getElementsByTagName('UNC')[0];
```

or, more simply (if you know there will only ever be one)

```
var z = xml.querySelector('Path>HD>UNC');
```

or, to get the first of "many"

```
var z = xml.querySelectorAll('Path>HD>UNC')[0];
```

I've ignored the fact that your XML is invalid, by the way, I figure that's a missed line when posting here

Comment: I wasn't aware about querySelector. it is much simple than trying to use GetElements.

Comment: beware, it may not be universally available - though it has been in internet explorer since IE8, so, pretty safe to use (I know I know, there's still a big percentage of IE7 out there)